# How to find the function from fixed points?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, fixed-points

A fixed point of a function $f$ is a number $t$ where $f(t)=t$. Geometrically, this means that the graph of $f$ crosses the line $y=x$ at the point $x=t$. Similarly, the graphs of $f\circ f$ and $f\circ f\circ f$ etc. also across the line $y=x$ when $x=t$.

How do we conclude linear functions **at most** can have one fixed point (with the exception of $f(x)=x$) while quadratics have at most two?

I have plotted an example in the case $f(x)=x^2-2$:

[image: Example plot]

Comment: $f(x)=x+1$ is a linear function and doesn't have one fixed point.

Comment: $f(x)=x$ is a linear function and has an infinity of fixed points.

Comment: I am saying a maximum of one (with the exception of f(x)=x). It can be 0.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you sure that $f(x)=x$ is the only exception?

Comment: Yes. Feel free to disprove :)

Comment: @bsd-boo: I have edited your question for MathJax, and to increase clarity. Hopefully the improvements will prevent it from being closed.

Comment: By definition, $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ has a fixed point at $t$ if and only if $f(t)=t$. If $f$ is a linear function, i.e. $f(x)=ax+b$, then finding the fixed points of $f$ amounts to solving the equation $at+b=t$ for $t$. This equation is equivalent to $(a-1)t=-b$. This in turn is equivalent to $a-1=b=0$ (which corresponds to the case where $f(x)\equiv x$) or $t=-b/(a-1)$  (which is the unique solution if $f(x)\not\equiv x$).

Comment: @bsd-boo: Your graph has a small error in it: $-2$ is not a fixed point of $f(x)=x^2-2$, since $(-2)^2-2$ equals $2$, not $-2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x) = ax + b$ is linear function, then equation $f(x) = x$ can be rearranged to
$$ ax + b = x \iff (a - 1)x = -b.$$
If $a\neq 1$, then we have unique solution $x = \frac b{1-a}$, while when $a = 1$ we either have infinitely many solutions when $b = 0$ (exception mentioned in the comments) to equation $0x = 0$ or no solutions when $b \neq 0$ to equation $0x = -b$.

When $f(x)$ is polynomial of degree $n \geq 2$, then
equation $f(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 x + a_0 = x$ where $a_n \neq 0$ can be rearranged to
$$
a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_2 x^2 + (a_1-1) x + a_0 = 0,
$$
so fixed points of $f(x)$ are precisely the roots of polynomial (of degree $n$)
$g(x) = f(x) - x$. According to [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), such polynomial can have at most $n$ real roots, so $f$ has at most $n$ fixed points.

The case $n = 1$ was special, because degree of $f(x) - x$ could be different than degree of $f(x)$.

Comment: This answer is mostly correct, but I think you have made a few small errors in the part about linear functions. The unique solution when $a\neq1$ is $x=b/(1-a)$. If $a=1$ and $b=0$, then the equation has infinitely many solutions (no exceptions here). However, if $a=1$ and $b\neq0$, then there are no solutions.